# Reading web.xml params in applicationscoped managed bean

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to read params in the web.xml file in a application scoped managed bean. When attempting to get the facescontext this returns null. Is there any other way to get the list of all params defined in the web xml?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>SOME_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>SOME_VALUE</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationParameters implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Object> parameters;

    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
        final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(facesContext != null) { //this is always null
            ExternalContext ctx = facesContext.getExternalContext();
            parameters = ctx.getInitParameterMap();
        }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen. What JSF impl/version are you using? Have you tried the latest, if possible/available?

Comment: jsf2.0 runnning on websphere. I'm noob on jsf stuff, but is it possible that there is any config somewhere that is needed? Or are the annotations enough?

Comment: you've got applicationscoped annotation in both javax.faces.bean and in javax.enterprise.context. I've used the one in javax.faces.bean, is this correct?

Comment: I'd look for an upgrade pack. Perhaps your Websphere is having an outdated JSF version which exposes this bug.